# Measuring raycast hitpoint of the specific object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

camera is casting a ray to any other object.
I am trying to measure hit points(x,y,z) of specific object(screen3D).
here is my code

```
public class EyeTrackingPoint : MonoBehaviour {
public float sphereRadius=250.0f;
public GameObject screen3D;
public Vector3 ScreenPosition;
private void Update()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Camera cam = Camera.main;
    Ray ray = new Ray(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.rotation * Vector3.forward * sphereRadius);
    if( Physics.Raycast( ray, out hit) || hit.collider.gameObject.Equals(screen3D)) 
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.point);   
    }
}
```

}

but, I got null reference exception error. what should I have to do to fix my error.
nullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
EyeTrackingPoint.Update () (at Assets/EyeTrackingPoint.cs:14)

EyetrackingPoint.cs:14

```
if( Physics.Raycast( ray, out hit) || hit.collider.gameObject.Equals(screen3D))
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with `||`. That should be `&&` not `||`.

The `||` means that next condition which is `hit.collider.gameObject.Equals(screen3D)` will be checked even when `Physics.Raycast( ray, out hit)` is `false`.

If `Physics.Raycast( ray, out hit)` is `false` and `hit.collider.gameObject.Equals(screen3D)` is executed, the `hit` variable will be null and you will get the null exception when you try to use `hit.collider`.

When you use `&&`, `hit.collider.gameObject.Equals(screen3D)` will only be checked if `Physics.Raycast( ray, out hit)` is `true` and this is the proper behavior you want.

So you should use this:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.collider.gameObject == screen3D)
{
    Debug.Log(hit.point);
}
```

OR

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
{
    if (hit.collider.gameObject == screen3D)
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.point);
    }
}
```